# Puppet gives SSL error because master is not running?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I started with two clean machines this time.

My master is running 12.04

> Version: 2.7.11-1ubuntu2
>
> Depends: ruby1.8, puppetmaster-common (= 2.7.11-1ubuntu2)

My client is 10.04

> Version: 2.6.3-0ubuntu1~lucid1
>
> Depends: puppet-common (=> 2.6.3-0ubuntu1~lucid1), ruby1.8

To setup Puppet tutorial:  http://shapeshed.com/setting-up-puppet-on-ubuntu-10-04/

To connect master and client:  http://shapeshed.com/connecting-clients-to-a-puppet-master/

The first time I tried to connect master to client failed with `SSL_connect error`. So I did `rm -rf /etc/puppet/ssl/`  to remove all the keys inside ssl folders.

It looked like it work.... BUT

```
client# puppet agent --server puppet --waitforce 60 --test
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/facter/util/resolution.rb:46: warning: Insecure world writable dir /etc/condor in PATH, mode 040777
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/puppet/defaults.rb:67: warning: Insecure world writable dir /etc/condor in PATH, mode 040777
info: Creating a new SSL key for giab10
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Caching certificate for ca
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for mybox123
info: Certificate Request fingerprint (md5): XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session

warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
info: Caching certificate for mybox123
err: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
warning: Not using cache on failed catalog

It cached but then it couldn't retrieve it.
```

Let me stop here.... worrying I would mess something up. But let's check master's status.

```
 * master is not running
```

WoW.... ???

```
master# service puppetmaster start
* Starting puppet master    [OK]
master# service puppetmaster status
 * master is not running
```

1. I think time is sync. Well, we are behind a firewall so the port to
   sync time is disbaled. I checked with `date` and they seem okay.
2. What about master not running? Is that the cause?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

---

**/var/lib/puppet/log/masterhttp.log**

```
[2012-06-30 00:13:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-06-30 00:13:25] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-06-30 00:13:25] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2012-06-30 00:19:40] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-06-30 00:19:40] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-06-30 00:19:40] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2012-06-30 00:28:58] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-06-30 00:28:58] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-06-30 00:28:58] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
[2012-06-30 15:31:25] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-06-30 15:31:25] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2012-06-30 15:31:25] WARN  TCPServer Error: Address already in use - bind(2)
```

---

```
    1 S puppet    5186     1  0  80   0 - 29410 poll_s 15:44 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ruby1.8 /usr/bin/puppet master --masterport=8140
    4 S root      5235  5005  0  80   0 -  2344 pipe_w 15:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto puppet

kill -9 5186
puppet master
service puppetmaster status
 * master is not running
```

---

I always have this error, but I always ignored it. http://pastebin.com/exbpArjv
What could it mean? Time sync? Package not installed? Then how could we do puppetca in the first place?

Comment: on the Master host, check `/var/log/puppet/puppetmaster.log` and paste the an error here. Also- if the puppet client wasn't able to see the Puppet Master, then it would say so. Something else is happening here.

Comment: @qweet Thanks! `/var/log/puppet` is `puppet:puppet` for group and owner. I have to access as root in order to get in there. Also, I don't have that file. I have `masterhttp.log  masterhttp.log.1.gz
`

Comment: Post something from `masterhttp.log`. It should give us a clue as to why it's not working.

Comment: @qweet I just did. However, it's inside /var/lib/puppet,because /var/log/puppet has an empty log file. Thanks. Like I said, how come these address are being used? When I say clean I mean I've deleted puppetmaster and puppet.

Comment: Might mean that you have a puppetmaster process still running, which has bound itself to the port that it likes to use. Try doing a `ps -elf | grep puppet` on the Master to see if there's an instance running.

Comment: @qweet Thanks. I did, but `puppetmaster status` still says NOPE. :( I checked the log and doesn't produce any more log.

Comment: Ok something's going on. Try `puppet master --debug --no-daemonize` and see what the master says when it boots up.

Comment: @qweet Thanks. Here is the log: http://pastebin.com/exbpArjv  I always ignored these errors.... what's the problem? I am trying to talk to puppet client.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3941/discussion-between-qweet-and-daniel-huger)

Answer (score 1):

Run `puppet master --debug --no-daemonize` and if you come to see

```
Error: Could not run: Address already in use - bind(2)
```

It probably means that the puppet master is already running. Try checking the output of

```
netstat -anpl | grep 8140
```

if you see a line referencing port 8140 with LISTEN, then that is probably your issue. (The puppet master process listens on port 8140 for incoming connections from clients by default.)

If you've followed the default setup for Ubuntu, apache will have started, listening on port 8140.

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

then carry on with the config.